# JerseyWebTarget IPv6 support?

Tags: java, jersey, ipv6

We are using glassfish Jersey library to communicate using RESTful APIs. We use resolveTemplate API to resolve the URL template with actual IP address.
Something like this:
private static final String API_URL_TMPL = "https://{nodeIp}:9000/api/v2/abc/";
private static final String VAR_NODE_IP = "nodeIp";

new JerseyWebTarget(API_URL_TMPL, jerseyClient).resolveTemplate(VAR_NODE_IP, nodeIp);

jerseyClient is created previously.
nodeIp value being passed is [6001::f816:3eff:fe87:c1a8]

We are hitting this issue:
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.UnknownHostException: %5B6001%3A%3Af816%3A3eff%3Afe87%3Ac1a8%5D

Does jersey even support IPv6 ?
How to overcome this?

Thanks !

Comment: The `6001::f816:3eff:fe87:c1a8` IPv6 address is bogus. All Global IPv6 addresses are in the `2000::/3` range.

Comment: This is inside our subnet. We are not using global routable IPv6 addresses. Hence 6001::/64 is OK. I can ping this address from the device console, so reachability is not an issue. [6001::f816:3eff:fe87:c1a8] is somehow getting changed (encoded) to %5B6001%3A%3Af816%3A3eff%3Afe87%3Ac1a8%5D.

Comment: "_Hence 6001::/64 is OK._" No, it is not. You can use [ULA](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4193) (`fc00::/7`) where the `fd00::/8` range is available for local assignment if you randomly choose the next 40 bits (Global ID) to get a `/48` prefix from which you can get 65,536 `/64` networks. You cannot simply make up your own addressing that way.